# How to correctly update spinner view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have 2 spinners each of them contains of text view and ProgressBar. 
When I select element in 1rst spinner on second sprinner should be seen ProgressBar and request to server should be made to grab some data and populate a spinner, after spinner was populated progressBar should be inivisble. 
Right now after selecting an element from 1rst spinner on second spinner ProgressBar is display (request is made) and ProgressBar  will be hiden only when item is selected from second spinner.
I do not know what should I change in code, please help.
This is my code:

Spinner:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View row = mInflater.inflate(...);
    TextView itemView = (TextView) row.findViewById(...);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(...);
    //mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    T item = getItem(position);
    String itemLabel = null;
        itemLabel = mContext.getString(R.string.dialog_filters_item, item.getName());

    }
    itemView.setText(itemLabel);
    return row;
}

@Override
public void setProgressBarVisibility(final boolean visibility) {
    if (mProgressBar != null) {
        if (visibility) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


        Log.v(TAG, "changed visibility on spinner " + visibility);
    }


}
```

Fragment with spinners:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    ....        //spinner1 && spniner2 methods run on UI Threads
    spinner1SetProgressBarVisibility(true);
    spinner2SetProgressBarVisibility(false);        //request to server
    mHost.populateSpinner1();       ....
    return v;
}


private void populateSpinner1Spinner(List<Data> dataServerItems) {
    Data dataAll = new Data();
    dataAll.setDepName(...);
    dataAll.setDepNumber(...);
    mDataItems.clear();
    mDataItems.add(dataAll);
    if (dataServerItems != null) {
        mDataItems.addAll(dataServerItems);
    }
    spinner1SetProgressBarVisibility(false);
    spinner2SetProgressBarVisibility(false);


    mSpinner1DataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
 private void populateSectionsSpinner(List<Data2> dataServerItems) {
    Data2 dataAll = new Data2();
    dataAll.setSectionName(getString(...));
    dataAll.setSectionNumber(...);
    mData2Items.clear();
    mData2Items.add(0, dataAll);
    if (dataServerItems != null) {
        mSectionItems.addAll(dataServerItems);
    spinner1SetProgressBarVisibility(false);
    spinner2SetProgressBarVisibility(false);
    mSpinner2DataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onItemSelected, position=" + position);
    switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner1:
            spinner1SetProgressBarVisibility(false);
              mHost.getData2();
            spinner2SetProgressBarVisibility(true);
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
                ...
                break;

            }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Not used
}

@Override
public void onDataUpdate(List<Data> dataServerItems) {
   populateSpinner1Spinner(List<Data> dataServerItems);

}
@Override
public void onData2Update(List<Data2> dataServerItems) {
     populateSpinner2Spinner(List<Data> dataServerItems);

}    private void spinner1SetProgressBarVisibility(final boolean isVisible) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSpinner1DataAdapter.setProgressBarVisibility(isVisible);
        }
    });
}

private void spinner2SetProgressBarVisibility(final boolean isVisible) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSpinner2DataAdapter.setProgressBarVisibility(isVisible);


        }
    });
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by CustomAdapter. On default visibility of progress bar is set to false